# Multiplying by inverse matrices?

Tags: math, directx, matrix, inverse

If I have a matrix which is a combination of World*View*Projection and I multiply it by the inverse of the projection does it yield the World*View matrix or something else? If not then how can I extract the World*View matrix from a World*View*Projection matrix?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you multiply on the right by the inverse of Projection, you will get World*View.

If you multiply on the left you'll get something entirely different, since matrix multiplication isn't commutative.

This assumes that Projection has an inverse.  Not all matrices do.

Comment: Projection matrices usually don't have inverses since they map to a lower dimensional space.

Comment: In math that's true, but in computer graphics usually the projection matrix is invertible.